# Building a proj4 string for readShapePoly in R

Tags: r, gis, proj

I have read in a shapefile of lodgepole pine seed planning units in R with `readShapePoly`, like so

```
spu <- readShapePoly("spus.shp")
```

When I map the spus alone, they show up.

```
plot(spu, border=TRUE)
```

When I try to add the shapefile to a map of Canada, where I know the spus should go, they do not show up.

```
map("worldHires","Canada", xlim=c(-141,-110), ylim=c(45,65), col="gray90", fill=TRUE)
plot(spu, add=TRUE, border=TRUE)
```

I think this is because the shapefile is missing the projection information contained in the .prj file:

```
PROJCS["NAD_1983_Albers",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Albers"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",1000000.0],
PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-126.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",50.0],
PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",58.5],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",45.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

The partial output of

```
summary(spu)

Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
Coordinates:
     min     max
x 642162.8 1870556
y 457057.2 1421478
Is projected: NA 
proj4string : [NA]
Data attributes:
```

shows that no projection information is associated with the spu object in R. I think I can fix this by using the correct `proj4string` with `readShapePoly,`but could not find how to translate the information in the .prj file into a proj4 string. How can I do this/is this the correct approach?

Comment: I'd suggest you to check for projections of both layers. I'd also use `rgdal::readOGR` instead. Did you try it? Would you mind to provide access to your data?

Comment: As @PauloCardoso suggested, try: `library(rgdal); spu <- readOGR('.', 'spus')`. Projection info in a .prj associated with the shp should be imported automagically.

Comment: Yes, thanks @PauloCardoso I do need to make sure my base map layer matches the projection of my data.

Comment: Once I got `rgdal` installed `readOGR` identified the projection correctly when I called `summary(spu)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert a .prj to proj4, you can use the command line tool `gdalsrsinfo`, as described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55196/how-can-i-get-the-proj4-string-or-epsg-code-from-a-shapefile-prj-file).

To run it from R, you could do:

```
system('gdalsrsinfo "spus.prj"')
```

where `spus.prj` is the full (or relative to wd) path to the .prj file.

Included in the returned info is the proj4 string.

Note that for this to work as provided here, the path containing gdalsrsinfo.exe should be included in the system PATH environment variable. Otherwise, you could provide the full path to gdalsrsinfo in the `system` call.

Comment: what is meant by "should be included in the system PATH environment variable"? how to do it?

Comment: PATH is a system variable that contains a set of directories that usually contain executables. Having a directory in PATH means that its contained files are executable without navigating to the directory itself. There's clear description of the steps required for adding to PATH in Windows [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm). For other operating systems, do a web search for something like `add directory to path variable osx`. There should be plenty of instructions online. Note that you will need to restart R/RStudio after modifying PATH.

Comment: A directory containing GDAL executables may already exist on your PATH. To determine this, you could open a command prompt (or terminal) window, and type `gdalsrsinfo`. If it returns info on the correct usage of `gdalsrsinfo`, you are in business. You can also see the contents of PATH from the command line with `echo %PATH%` (in Windows).

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation! I have to try it.